# How do I increase HTTPfs's timeout parameter

Tags: hadoop, lzo

Right now, my ingest process using HTTPfs is timing out around a minute. Can this timeout setting be adjusted?

```
9:52:17.486 PM  ERROR   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation 
PriviledgedActionException as:manager (auth:PROXY) via httpfs (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
9:52:17.486 PM  WARN    httpfsaudit 
FAILED [PUT:/really_large.log.lzo] response [Internal Server Error] Read timed out
9:52:17.486 PM  WARN    org.apache.hadoop.fs.http.server.HttpFSExceptionProvider    
[[PUT, /really_large.log.lzo, Internal Server Error, Read timed out]:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out] response [{}] {}
```

Comment: Same problem, 3 years after :)